# REGEX to match relative urls inside href attribute in a html file

Tags: c#, html, regex, url, relative-path

I am making a c# code that converts relative to absolute URLs in href and src attributes of an inputted HTML code in a Richtextbox when the user clicks a button, using a path that the user input. I need a regex that only matches relative URLs inside href and src attributes and converts them to absolute. this is what I am trying to achieve:
example:
if the path that the user inputted: https://example.com/page
and the html code in Richtextbox is :

```
<a href="https://example.com">click</a>
<a href="page1.html">click</a>
<img src="/img1.png" />
<img src="../img2.png" />
```

this is the result that I want for the html code:

```
<a href="https://example.com">click</a> //this doesn't change
<a href="https://example.com/page/page1.html">click</a>
<img src="https://example.com/page/img1.png" />
<img src="https://example.com/img2.png" />
```

I have only been able to come up with regex that matches href attributes .*href=(["])(.*?)\1
but I can't come up with a regex that does the work above (relative to absolute).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips for you:

1. Please don't use regex to parse HTML. It could break the universe. See here for more info: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
2. Instead, you can use HTML Agility Pack, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100393/4506315) SO answer

Comment: I am afraid using HTML agility pack might slow down the process

Comment: It depends on how big is your HTML document. Regex is not very performance too